# Windows.Services.Maps not available for Win8.1 RT App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm trying to use MapLocationFinder -which is part of Windows.Services.Maps- in a Windows 8.1 App Project. However the namespace cannot be found. It can't find Windows.Services.
I can't find anything online and there is nothing in "Add Reference". According to another so question this API is only available to WinRT Apps but my App is a WinRT App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes/features are only available from a Windows 10+ Windows Runtime app or a Windows Phone 8.1.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.services.maps.aspx